# Face 500 Error in PHP Internal Server Error

Tags: php, json

I'm add this code in php :

`echo '{"YourMessageis":"' alishcode($input,$message_key);'"}'`

But I face 500 server error. What happend 
and how can I remove 16777 from php response
`16777 w13 r s3 w2 r s3 w36`
and get `w13 r s3 w2 r s3 w36` only?

Comment: `echo '{"YourMessageis":"' . alishcode($input,$message_key) . '"}';` concat your string properly

Comment: Try to use `json_encode` this way you avoid typing syntax errors. Like: `echo json_encode(array(
 'YourMessageis' =>  alishcode($input,$message_key)
));` PHP syntax is then highlighted and mistakes can be detected while you're typing.

Comment: for example how can i remove 16777 http://api.uplaytube.com/key visit this address

Comment: @Matt Dear sir this code is very nice and work fine how to i remove 16777 from message {"YourMessageis":"16777 w13 r s3 w2 r s3 w36"} like this

Comment: `alishcode()` is not a native PHP function. Can you provide me the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `.`Reformat it like this:

`echo '{"YourMessageis":"'. alishcode($input,$message_key).'"}';`

Comment: how can i remove `16777` from this code after response => `16777 w13 r s3 w2 r s3 w36`